Finite two-relator groups and quotients of knot groups
Let $G$ be a one-relator group $\langle A \mid R = 1 \rangle$. Then clearly $G$ is finite if and only if it is cyclic of finite order, i.e. can be given by a presentation $\langle a \mid a^n = 1 \rangle$ for some $n > 0$.
1. What are the finite two-relator groups?
This question might be unanswerable. An indication of why this problem might be difficult comes from a classical example due to Dehn. He shows that for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $m \in \{ 2, 3, 4, 5\}$, the group $$ G_{m,n} = \langle a,b  \mid a^2 = b^3, \: (ab)^m b^{3n} = 1 \rangle $$
is finite, i.e. a quotient of the trefoil knot group. Indeed, he shows that these groups fit in short exact sequences
$$
1 \longrightarrow C_k \longrightarrow G_{m,n} \longrightarrow H_m \longrightarrow 1
$$
where $k \in \{ 3n + 5, 4n + 10, 6n + 20, 12n + 50 \}$ and $H_m \in \{ S_3, A_4, S_4, A_5 \}$ depending on the value of $m$ (indexed as above). Thus the question is already quite non-trivial even when one of the relators is rather simple. A partial and valuable answer to Question 1 would hence be an answer to the following question:
2. What are the finite (relative) one-relator quotients of the trefoil knot group $\langle a, b \mid a^2 = b^3 \rangle$?
In particular, is $G_{m,n}$ finite for any $m>5$ and $n > 0$? (I suspect not). Any thoughts would be welcome!

You don't need Freiheisatz for the 1st statement: it is clear that a 1-relator group on $\ge 2$ generators has infinite abelianization.

The keyword "balanced presentation" seems to lead to some previous work on the subject.

@YCor Sure, good point, I was initially going to write something stronger. I've removed that. For balanced presentations, my impression is that due to the Andrews-Curtis Conjecture a big theme is finding balanced presentations for the trivial group (rather than classifying which finite groups can appear). But maybe I'm looking in the wrong place?

I googled « "balanced presentations" "finite groups"».

For the special case of Question 2, you should look again at Dehn’s paper. He exhibits infinitely many “Dehn fillings” (as they are now known) that act cocompactly on the hyperbolic plane. So unless your parametrisation in terms of $m,n$ is very different from his, the answer should be “no”.

@HJRW Thanks! In fact, I did not get the result from Dehn's paper (which one is it from?), but rather one by Magnus (1930).

It’s a paper from around 1910 where he constructs infinitely many homology 3-spheres. I can look up the exact citation later.

Re: Question 1, it is certainly open whether there is an algorithm to decide if a two-relator group is finite.

The Dehn paper is: Dehn, M. Über die Topologie des dreidimensionalen Raumes. Math. Ann. 69 (1910), no. 1, 137–168. I suspect your German is better than mine, but in case not there is, as usual, an excellent English translation in Stillwell's book of Dehn's paper on topology.

One question which immediately springs to (my) mind is to characterise language complexity of word problem for finite 2-generator, 2-relator groups. It should not be that bad; can it be somewhere around ELT?

@DenisT: it is certainly unknown whether all 2-generator, 2-relator groups have solvable word problem. Personally, I doubt the finiteness assumption will help (though I may be missing something).

@HJRW Virtually free groups = groups with context free word problem, so finiteness assumption indeed helps a lot.

@DenisT I don’t understand what you mean. The word problem of any finite group is a regular language.

@DenisT: Sure, but the virtually free hypothesis gives you a lot of extra geometry to use. In contrast, we know literally nothing about the structure of two-relator groups. You have to find a way to use the hypotheses!

Here is a related question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/59937/efficient-presentations-for-finite-groups

Several references here give families of 2-relator finite simple groups. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3273282

Question 1:
As mentioned in comments, presentations with the same number of generators and relations are called balanced. The triviality problem for balanced presentations appears to be a question of Magnus (see Ian Leary's comment below, cf. Question 13.9 on Bestvina's problem list).
It is in a similar vein to the more famous Andrews--Curtis conjecture and, just like Andrews--Curtis, is wide open. Relaxing "triviality" to "finiteness" and restricting to two relations isn't going to help, so I feel confident in claiming that Question 1 (in the sense of algorithmic decidability) is an open problem.
Question 2:
Again, I doubt there is a reasonable full description.
Edit: apologies, my earlier answer was a little glib here, although I think the spirit -- there's unlikely to be a satisfying classification -- is correct.
Groups of this form are central extensions of generalised triangle groups in the sense of
Baumslag, Morgan, Shalen, Generalized triangle groups. Math. Proc. Cambridge Philos. Soc. 102 (1987), no. 1, 25–31.
There's a disparate literature on this subject, but I'd be very surprised if it is completely understood which ones are finite. (This feels in a similar vein to the isomorphism problem for one-relator groups, say.)
For your specific question about Dehn's family, note that
$G_{m,n}/\langle b^3\rangle\cong \langle a,b\mid a^2,b^3,(ab)^m\rangle$
which is the $(2,3,m)$-triangle group. In particular, $G_{m,n}$ is infinite whenever $m>5$ and $n>0$.

Martin Bridson's formulation of the triviality question on Bestvina's problem list is a nice one, but the question already appeared in the 1965 version of the Kourovka Notebook as question 1.12 (asked by Greendlinger who attributed it to Magnus).

@IJL: That makes much more sense -- I'm delighted to learn it has a classical source!
